# Google App Engine Project Root Location

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-shell

Apologies for the seemingly obvious question, but I figure the answer might help others. I can't for the life of me find documentation on the filepath within the Google App Engine VM (Cloud Shell) where I can find the static files being served from. I need to pull the latest upstream changes from a private github repo.

Note that I navigated elsewhere in the VM and even restarting the session didn't put me in a default project root path within the VM as I expected it to.

Comment: App Engine & Cloud Shell are different things. Cloud Shell is an interactive shell, running in a different machine, entirely handled by Google. You can deploy from there your code to App Engine, as you can do from your own machine, but the relation ends there. Besides that, your question is weirdly phrased and hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: So, in the past, I've done a remote pull from github into the VM via Cloud Shell. Simply put, I can't find the directory in the VM from which I made that git pull. I understand that they're different and apologize that I have very little understanding of them, admittedly, but the only thing I'm missing right now is the directory location, the rest of the process I've got under control.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several issues to address here:

#### The Cloud Shell is a *virtual* shell

> [Google Cloud Shell is an interactive shell environment for Google
>   Cloud Platform.](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/features)

The environment where you're working is a container running in a VM in a Google-owned project inside GCP.

You can verify this by checking the metadata server (only available for GCP VMs):

```
curl -H 'Metadata-Flavor:Google' "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/?recursive=true&alt=text"
```

In the metadata provided you'll see how this container is created and configured.

The Cloud Shell is tied to the user, so you'll always access the same environment if you access it with the same credentials, no matter the project. However, if you access with a different user, you'll get a different environment.

#### You can't access GAE standard instances

GAE is a fully managed environment, and you won't be able to access it. In this way, you won't be able to find the root of the running app engine project.

However, by the way GAE deploys your code, it uses a staging bucket to gather the code before compiling. You can find your staging bucket through the [App Engine Admin API](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/appengine/v1/appengine.apps.get). This is usually `staging.<PROJECT_ID>.appspot.com`, although you can change this configuration. You can get your files from there.

#### You can access GAE flex apps

However, the deployment in flex gets your files, build a Docker container with them, and then deploys this container inside a VM.

As per [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/debugging-an-instance#connecting_to_the_instance), you can connect directly to your container by running:

```
gcloud app instances ssh [INSTANCE-NAME] --service [SERVICE] --version [VERSION] 
docker exec -it gaeapp /bin/bash
```

#### Regarding your issue

According what you say in the comments of the question, your issue could come from a myriad of places. From changing the shell you're connecting to, to resetting your shell environment (deleting all the files), to a thousand different possible problems.

The best way to think about it is regard the Cloud Shell as a temporal environment to run commands, but not as a virtual machine.

Knowing that, you could mount a persistent filesystem ([GCS through GCSFuse](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse), [Cloud Filestore](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/mounting-fileshares), ...) to persist your work, or simply use Git to have your work always synced on a [repo](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/).

GAE Flex has some nice CI integrations, so that's a plus for going the Git route.

Comment: This is perfect, thanks @Jofre. I think the real source of my issue is that I had deployed this app a year or so ago and I think some of the valid paths to interact with it are no longer available. So my expectation around how to interact with it is no longer valid. Thanks for the thorough breakdown!