# Google Cloud Spring Boot InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I've attempted to deploy a spring-boot app to google cloud. It runs fine locally, however when deploying it to App Engine and trying to hit the landing page, I get a 404 error and a huge amount of `InvocationTargetException`s:

```
java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.Jre9Compat.jarFileNewInstance(Jre9Compat.java:209) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar.<init>(JarFileUrlJar.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:383) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs(StandardJarScanner.java:318) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.doScanClassPath(StandardJarScanner.java:282) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:233) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.46.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:104) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.46.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:83) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.46.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5161) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar!/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar!/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:829) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar!/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar!/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar!/:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar!/:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:450) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar!/:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:199) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar!/:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:182) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar!/:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar!/:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar!/:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar!/:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar!/:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:438) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar!/:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:337) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar!/:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1336) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar!/:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1325) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar!/:2.5.0]
    at samuelb.capripol.CapripolApplication.main(CapripolApplication.java:17) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[capripol-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[capripol-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[capripol-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[capripol-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor33.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.Jre9Compat.jarFileNewInstance(Jre9Compat.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar!/:na]
    ... 54 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /workspace/lib/modelmapper-2.3.5.jar
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:55) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:149) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(LinuxFileSystemProvider.java:99) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1764) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1239) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:732) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:849) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:247) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:348) ~[na:na]
    ... 58 common frames omitted
```

It's also probably worth mentioning that deploying using gcloud app deploy gives an error that I have exceeded the 10000 file limit which isn't true, the app has not even 500.

app.yaml:

```
runtime: java11
# this makes no difference
# entrypoint: java -Xmx64m -jar capripol-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
instance_class: F2

handlers:
- url: /.*
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  script: auto
- url: /login
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  script: auto
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>samuelB</groupId>
    <artifactId>capripol</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Capripol</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <!-- <properties>
    

    
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

      
        <webjars-bootstrap.version>3.3.6</webjars-bootstrap.version>
        <webjars-jquery-ui.version>1.11.4</webjars-jquery-ui.version>
        <webjars-jquery.version>2.2.4</webjars-jquery.version>
        <wro4j.version>1.8.0</wro4j.version>

        <jacoco.version>0.8.5</jacoco.version>
        <nohttp-checkstyle.version>0.0.4.RELEASE</nohttp-checkstyle.version>
        <spring-format.version>0.0.25</spring-format.version> -->
    <!-- </properties> -->

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.RC1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
      <!-- Use Spring Milestone Repository -->
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
        <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>samuelb.capripol.CapripolApplication</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <version>1</version>
                    <projectId>GCLOUD_CONFIG</projectId>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

directory structure:

[image: directory structure]

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

This it the debug log from gcloud app deploy `--verbosity=debug`

```
DEBUG: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: This deployment has too many files. New versions are limited to 10000 files for this app.
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest
  fieldViolations:
  - description: This deployment has too many files. New versions are limited to 10000
      files for this app.
    field: version.deployment.files[...]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 984, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 809, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/app/deploy.py", line 130, in Run
    use_legacy_apis=args.use_legacy_apis)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/deploy_util.py", line 691, in RunDeploy
    service_account=service_account)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/deploy_util.py", line 463, in Deploy
    extra_config_settings, service_account)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/appengine_api_client.py", line 177, in DeployService
    service_account_email)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/appengine_api_client.py", line 260, in _CreateVersion
    return self.client.apps_services_versions.Create(create_request)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/third_party/apis/appengine/v1/appengine_v1_client.py", line 830, in Create
    config, request, global_params=global_params)
  File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 737, in _RunMethod
    return self.ProcessHttpResponse(method_config, http_response, request)
  File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 743, in ProcessHttpResponse
    self.__ProcessHttpResponse(method_config, http_response, request))
  File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 610, in __ProcessHttpResponse
    http_response, method_config=method_config, request=request)
apitools.base.py.exceptions.HttpBadRequestError: HttpError accessing <https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1/apps/pollog/services/default/versions?alt=json>: response: <{'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'date': 'Sun, 22 Aug 2021 01:18:11 GMT', 'server': 'ESF', 'cache-control': 'private', 'x-xss-protection': '0', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'status': '400', 'content-length': '517', '-content-encoding': 'gzip'}>, content <{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "This deployment has too many files. New versions are limited to 10000 files for this app.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "field": "version.deployment.files[...]",
            "description": "This deployment has too many files. New versions are limited to 10000 files for this app."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the detailed logs received by deploying your app to the App Engine with the `--verbosity=debug` flag? 

The 10,000 file limit can be reached if getting deployed from the framework.

Comment: @FaridShumbar the log has been added

Comment: Please have a look at this [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/1034634/i-want-to-increase-the-number-of-files-that-can-be-gcp-deployed-to-10-000-or-mor). Let me know if it answers your question.

Comment: I don't have other 10000 files so I have no need to increase the cap. I'm really not sure why it says that I have over 10000. Could it be including libraries and stuff that my project references? If so, I'm unsure what files can or should be ignored

Comment: This is actually a reasonably common error. Websphere has a similar problem.

Comment: What is the java runtime version for your local vs google cloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem can be related to the fact that you are configuring the `maven-jar-plugin` to include a reference to your application dependencies in the MANIFEST classpath.

When your application is repackaged with the [spring-boot-maven-plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging), it will generate a [file](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html) in which your references to the indicated libraries are no longer valid.

As a consequence, when App Engine tries starting your app, your jar is loaded and the `NoSuchFileException` error is raised when it tries finding the different classpath dependencies.

In order to avoid the problem, please, try removing the following configuration from your `maven-jar-plugin`:

```xml
<configuration>
  <archive>
    <manifest>
       <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
       <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
       <mainClass>samuelb.capripol.CapripolApplication</mainClass>
    </manifest>
  </archive>
</configuration>
```

Spring will take care of providing the right dependencies and main class.

Regarding the [10,000 file limit](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/how-requests-are-handled#quotas_and_limits) issue, please, review your archive contents and see if you can optimize it to only use the actually required elements.

As you probably are using App Engine Flexible environment, try performing ssh into your provisioned VM instances and see what is going on:

```sh
gcloud app instances ssh --service=s1 --version=v1 i1 --container=gaeapp
```

Please, see the [relevant documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/instances/ssh). This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51852385/google-app-engine-project-root-location) can be of help a well.

Comment: That fixed the FileNotFoundException, thanks! I'm still running into the 404 error however. It could be worth mentioning that I get an error in developer tools: 
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://pollog.ts.r.appspot.com/login' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure favicon 'http://pollog.ts.r.appspot.com/login'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: Hi @Rigg97. I am happy to hear that the `NoSuchFileException` error was solved with the suggested change. I don't think the favicon error reported by chrome is the root of the 404 problem. Please, be sure that your favicon exists, and review its `link` `href` and provide the proper value. Regarding the 404 problem, please, review your GAE logs, just locate your service and under tools navigate to the [log explorer](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/writing-application-logs#viewing_logs), or use `gcloud`: `gcloud app logs tail`; try to see what is going on, probably it will

Comment: give you some guidance about the problem. Please, can you try?

Comment: The only logs I received are as follows:
`2021-09-03 08:03:47 default[1]  "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 404
2021-09-03 08:03:47 default[1]  "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 302`

It doesn't seem like anything's broken, but maybe the root of the app has been configured to something other than the GAE supplied domain 'pollog.ts.r.appspot.com'.  Or perhaps the error I mentioned in my previous comment is blocking any request to the app?

Comment: @Rigg97 it looks like a separate issue. Please create a new thread on Stack. Please also consider accepting jccampanero's answer as it solved the initial problem. Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much @FaridShumbar. Just for completeness, Rigg97, do not look at the errors now, try to review your logs at the moment in which you deployed your application looking for errors, or deploy you app again and review the logs now: I'm afraid your application is not starting properly, and this is why the load balancer which serves your app engine service is reporting the `404` error.

Comment: I've marked your answer and awarded the bounty, thanks for the help. I've created a separate issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69053987/google-app-engine-spring-boot-gives-a-404-error

Comment: Thank you very much @Rigg97. I will be glad to help you with the new question if I can.

Answer (score 1):

The error about exceeding the 10,000 file limit shows up because the libraries files are also counted.

This looks like something that could be improved by Google, so you could create a [Public issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) about this design and to request a solution that would allow to not count the library files or, for instance, to increase this limit.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor it explains why I couldn't deploy, but my issue lies at the root of the NoSuchFileException