# Google App Engine Spring Boot gives a 404 error

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

When deploying my Spring Boot application to Google App Engine, I receive a 404 error when trying to access the web application. The app runs fine locally, but refuses to work on the app engine. I deploy the app using the command `mvn package appengine:deploy -Dapp.deploy.projectId=pollog`.

The following are the logs after deploying the application:

```
2021-09-04 08:49:00 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:00.629  INFO 10 --- [           main] samuelb.capripol.CapripolApplication     : Starting CapripolApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 11.0.11 on localhost with PID 10 (/workspace/capripol-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by www-data in /workspace)
2021-09-04 08:49:00 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:00.635  INFO 10 --- [           main] samuelb.capripol.CapripolApplication     : The following profiles are active: mysql
2021-09-04 08:49:02 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:02.204  INFO 10 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-09-04 08:49:02 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:02.358  INFO 10 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 140 ms. Found 9 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-09-04 08:49:03 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:03.259  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-09-04 08:49:03 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:03.275  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-09-04 08:49:03 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:03.275  INFO 10 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.46]
2021-09-04 08:49:03 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:03.898  INFO 10 --- [           main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2021-09-04 08:49:04 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:04.190  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-09-04 08:49:04 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:04.190  INFO 10 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3475 ms
2021-09-04 08:49:04 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:04.561  WARN 10 --- [           main] o.s.h.c.j.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder    : For Jackson Kotlin classes support please add "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin" to the classpath
2021-09-04 08:49:04 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:04.663  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.a.s.GcpCloudSqlAutoConfiguration : Default MYSQL JdbcUrl provider. Connecting to jdbc:mysql://google/pollog?cloudSqlInstance=pollog:australia-southeast1:prod-instance&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&useSSL=false with driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
2021-09-04 08:49:04 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:04.677  WARN 10 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.a.s.GcpCloudSqlAutoConfiguration : spring.datasource.username is not specified. Setting default username.
2021-09-04 08:49:04 default[1]  Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
2021-09-04 08:49:04 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:04.877  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-09-04 08:49:04 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:04.995  INFO 10 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.31.Final
2021-09-04 08:49:05 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:05.246  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-09-04 08:49:05 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:05.426  INFO 10 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-09-04 08:49:05 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:05.432  WARN 10 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource  : Registered driver with driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
2021-09-04 08:49:05 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:05.576  INFO 10 --- [           main] c.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory   : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [pollog:australia-southeast1:prod-instance].
2021-09-04 08:49:05 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:05.576  INFO 10 --- [           main] c.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory   : Using GAE Unix Sockets
2021-09-04 08:49:06 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:06.660  INFO 10 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-09-04 08:49:06 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:06.716  INFO 10 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
2021-09-04 08:49:06 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:06.762  INFO 10 --- [onnection adder] c.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory   : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [pollog:australia-southeast1:prod-instance].
2021-09-04 08:49:06 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:06.763  INFO 10 --- [onnection adder] c.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory   : Using GAE Unix Sockets
2021-09-04 08:49:06 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:06.791  INFO 10 --- [onnection adder] c.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory   : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [pollog:australia-southeast1:prod-instance].
2021-09-04 08:49:06 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:06.791  INFO 10 --- [onnection adder] c.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory   : Using GAE Unix Sockets
2021-09-04 08:49:06 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:06.812  INFO 10 --- [onnection adder] c.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory   : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [pollog:australia-southeast1:prod-instance].
2021-09-04 08:49:06 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:06.812  INFO 10 --- [onnection adder] c.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory   : Using GAE Unix Sockets
2021-09-04 08:49:06 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:06.840  INFO 10 --- [onnection adder] c.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory   : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [pollog:australia-southeast1:prod-instance].
2021-09-04 08:49:06 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:06.840  INFO 10 --- [onnection adder] c.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory   : Using GAE Unix Sockets
2021-09-04 08:49:06 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:06.859  INFO 10 --- [onnection adder] c.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory   : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [pollog:australia-southeast1:prod-instance].
2021-09-04 08:49:06 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:06.859  INFO 10 --- [onnection adder] c.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory   : Using GAE Unix Sockets
2021-09-04 08:49:06 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:06.882  INFO 10 --- [onnection adder] c.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory   : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [pollog:australia-southeast1:prod-instance].
2021-09-04 08:49:06 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:06.882  INFO 10 --- [onnection adder] c.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory   : Using GAE Unix Sockets
2021-09-04 08:49:06 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:06.908  INFO 10 --- [onnection adder] c.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory   : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [pollog:australia-southeast1:prod-instance].
2021-09-04 08:49:06 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:06.909  INFO 10 --- [onnection adder] c.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory   : Using GAE Unix Sockets
2021-09-04 08:49:06 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:06.925  INFO 10 --- [onnection adder] c.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory   : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [pollog:australia-southeast1:prod-instance].
2021-09-04 08:49:06 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:06.926  INFO 10 --- [onnection adder] c.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory   : Using GAE Unix Sockets
2021-09-04 08:49:06 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:06.943  INFO 10 --- [onnection adder] c.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory   : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [pollog:australia-southeast1:prod-instance].
2021-09-04 08:49:06 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:06.944  INFO 10 --- [onnection adder] c.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory   : Using GAE Unix Sockets
2021-09-04 08:49:08 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:08.151  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-09-04 08:49:08 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:08.166  INFO 10 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-09-04 08:49:09 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:09.012  WARN 10 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-09-04 08:49:09 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:09.552  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure Ant [pattern='/css/**'] with []
2021-09-04 08:49:09 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:09.553  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure Ant [pattern='/js/**'] with []
2021-09-04 08:49:09 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:09.553  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure Ant [pattern='/images/**'] with []
2021-09-04 08:49:09 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:09.874  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@4cb957b8, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@45b32dfe, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@56846330, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@3cdc7b09, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@7bdf61ad, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@4a1a256d, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@22d9ca63, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@d611f1c, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@7364eed1, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@6cfbbff7, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@750a04ec, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@39dec536]
2021-09-04 08:49:10 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:10.173  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.core.DefaultCredentialsProvider  : Default credentials provider for Google Compute Engine.
2021-09-04 08:49:10 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:10.173  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.core.DefaultCredentialsProvider  : Scopes in use by default credentials: [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform]
2021-09-04 08:49:10 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:10.186  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.a.c.GcpContextAutoConfiguration  : The default project ID is pollog
2021-09-04 08:49:10 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:10.372  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2021-09-04 08:49:10 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:10.383  INFO 10 --- [           main] samuelb.capripol.CapripolApplication     : Started CapripolApplication in 10.788 seconds (JVM running for 12.207)
2021-09-04 08:49:10 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:10.384  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean      : Application availability state LivenessState changed to CORRECT
2021-09-04 08:49:10 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:10.387  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean      : Application availability state ReadinessState changed to ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC
2021-09-04 08:49:10 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:10.448  INFO 10 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-09-04 08:49:10 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:10.448  INFO 10 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-09-04 08:49:10 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:49:10.450  INFO 10 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms
2021-09-04 08:49:10 default[1]  "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 404
2021-09-04 08:49:10 default[1]  "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 302
2021-09-04 08:49:10 default[1]  "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 404
2021-09-04 08:52:32 default[1]  2021-09-04 08:52:32.255  INFO 10 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean      : Application availability state ReadinessState changed from ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC to REFUSING_TRAFFIC
2021-09-04 08:52:35 default[1]  {"severity": "WARNING", "message": "App is listening on port 8080. We recommend your app listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable to take advantage of an NGINX layer on port 8080."}\n
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>samuelB</groupId>
    <artifactId>capripol</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Capripol</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.RC1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
      <!-- Use Spring Milestone Repository -->
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <version>1</version>
                    <projectId>GCLOUD_CONFIG</projectId>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always

spring.profiles.active=mysql

spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

spring.resources.chain.strategy.content.enabled=true
spring.resources.chain.strategy.content.paths=/**
```

application-mysql.properties:

```
database=mysql

# Delete the rest of the original content of the file and replace with the following:
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.database-name=pollog
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name=pollog:australia-southeast1:prod-instance
spring.datasource.password = password123

# Initialize the database since the newly created Cloud SQL database has no tables. The following flag is for Spring Boot 2.
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

main:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CapripolApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CapripolApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(CapripolApplication.class);
    }

    @Configuration
    public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                    .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/", "classpath:/images/") //tells Spring the location of resources
                    .setCachePeriod(0);
        }
    }
```

WebSecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();
    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    //configuring datasource
    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager customAuthenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return authenticationManager();
    }

    //Tells Spring to 'ignore' or 'not navigate' these when trying to access files under their paths
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**");
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll() //these permit which roles can access whaich pages, i.e. any can login
                .antMatchers("/Admin").hasAnyAuthority("Admin", "Super Admin")//only admins/ superadmins can access admin page
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")//defines page used for logging in
                .failureUrl("/login?error")//page for failed login
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")//page after successful login
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                    .invalidSessionUrl("/login");
    }
}
```

app.yaml:

```
runtime: java11
# entrypoint: java -Xmx64m -jar capripol-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
instance_class: F2

handlers:
- url: /.*
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  script: auto
- url: /login
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  script: auto
```

EDIT: I tried using a larger instace type F4, F4_1G but this made no difference. I also added the following to suppress the warning about the port but this made no difference:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SpringApplication.run(CapripolApplication.class, args);
        int port = Integer.parseInt(System.getenv().getOrDefault("PORT", "8080"));
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(port), 0);

        // Set root URI path.
        server.createContext("/", (t) -> {
        byte[] response = "Hello World!".getBytes();
        t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length);
        try (OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody()) {
            os.write(response);
        }
        });

        // Create a second URI path.
        server.createContext("/foo", (t) -> {
        byte[] response = "Foo!".getBytes();
        t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length);
        try (OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody()) {
            os.write(response);
        }
        });

        server.start();
    }
```

Comment: Are you providing your own login page? Are you trying using the [Spring provided](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/jc.html#jc-httpsecurity)?

Comment: I'm using my own login page which I automatically redirect to if the user is not currently logged in. It works fine locally just not on the App Engine

Comment: can you share your app,yaml file?

Comment: @RafaelLemos I have now added the app.yaml

Comment: Hi @Rigg97. Sorry for the late reply. Thank you very much for the feedback. You are right, I forgot you mentioned that locally it runs fine. One thing you can try first is modifying your `app.yaml` `handlers` section. Please, be aware that the rules are evaluated in the order in which they appear; as a consequence, the first rule you defined will handle everything. In addition, `redirect_http_response_code` only has meaning if combined with `secure`. Pease, can trying defining your `handlers` section like this: `- url: /.*
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  script: auto`

Comment: @jccampanero no problem at all. I've made the change and it appears to make no difference

Comment: Hi @Rigg97. Thank you... I am sorry to hear that it does not work either. The app seems to start properly. In any case, can you try a bigger instance type? One with further resources. Spring usually requires more CPU and memory than the allocated for a F2 instance. Please, can you try? I hope it helps.

Comment: I tried both F4 and F4_1G, no luck. I also tried listening on the PORT specified to suppress the NGINX warning, but again no luck.

Comment: @Rigg97 I am sorry to hear that it does not work either. Please, regarding the warning and port, do not implement the server in the way exemplified in the GCP docs; as you are using Spring Boot, try the following configuration property in `application.properties` instead: `server.port=${PORT:8080}`. Please, can you fix the `app.yaml` handlers section as above mentioned and perform this change and try again?

Comment: @Rigg97 In fact, it can very likely the reason of the error because nginx is not serving your requests on port 80. Please, can you try the change suggested in the previous comment? In addition, are you able to access your application on port `8080`? Perhaps you need to adapt your firewall rules.

Comment: I've set server.port=${PORT:8080}, the application now runs on port 8081: Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) with context path ''. Still receiving the 404, the handler changes were also implemented as of my previous comment. Trying both https://pollog.ts.r.appspot.com:8080/login and https://pollog.ts.r.appspot.com:8081/login produces Site can't be reached

Comment: It's kind of hard to know where the issue is. For what I can see, seems that everything is fine but it could be that some files are not being correctly uploaded to GCP when deploying with maven, also, It could be the cause that you are depending on or declaring some absolutes paths on his code, which might also cause this, is this the case?

Comment: This issue is still unsolved, I've given up on it for the most part.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to solve it too and found out that the path or route was wrong.Try looking on postman to see if it works.
pd: I found out that my parameters were also wrong. datasource-username should be the one was created when registering on google cloud